# Calculate the maximum area (maximum value)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, optimization

TX farmer has 100 metres of fencing to use to make a rectangular enclosure for sheep as shown.

He will use existing walls for two sides of the enclosure and leave an opening of 2 metres for a gate.[image: schema of enclosure]

a)  Show that the area of the enclosure is given by: $A = 102x – x^2.$

b)  Find the value of x that will give the maximum possible area.

c)  Calculate the maximum possible area.

How do I assign the two variables for area ? Can anyone assist me in solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your picture, one side of the rectangle is x.
Since you have 100 metres, this means the other side has length (100 - x) + 2 = 102 - x.
So, the Area A = $(102 - x) * x = 102x - x^2$

The maximum area occurs where $\frac{dA}{dx} = 102 - 2x = 0$
or where $x = 51$

So, the max area A = $102(51) - 51^2$

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: thank you for your assistance and guiding me in the solution.
Area=length x width

Width = x
Length of the enclosure parallel to the wall = (100-x) +2 
=102 - x
Area= x(102-x)
Area, A = 102x-x^2
dA/dx=102- 2x

At Stationary Point
dA/dx=0  ⇒ 102 – 2x = 0

2x=102
x=51

the maximum area occurs when x = 51
and 
Area, A= (102x-x^2)
= 102x51 – (51)^2
= 2600